# How to stop a function with button?

Tags: javascript

This is a countdown timer and I want to stop it with a button. (I'm working on html and js for 3 days with today, sorry for my mistakes :D)

```js
function countDown(a) {
  var timeleft = 60 * a;
  document.getElementById('btn0000').disabled = true;
  document.getElementById('btn1000').disabled = true;

  var downloadTimer = setInterval(function() {

    var seconds = Math.floor((timeleft) % 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor((timeleft / 60) % 60);
    document.getElementById("countdown1").innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    timeleft -= 1;

    if (timeleft <= 0) {
      clearInterval(downloadTimer);
      document.getElementById("countdown1").innerHTML = "Finished"
      document.getElementById('btn0000').disabled = false;
      document.getElementById('btn1000').disabled = false;
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="countdown1">Timer</div>
<button id="btn0000" onclick="countDown(10)">10 min</button>
<button id="btn1000" onclick="countDown(5)">5 min</button>
<button id="btnStop">Stop</button>
```

Comment: Not sure why you didn't get to the solution. You already are using the solution to hte problem: `clearInterval(downloadTimer);`. You just need to store the value in some local variable. After that just bind the `onclick` event of the `Stop` button to a function which calls the mentioned `clearInterval`

Comment: You should have done a search before, there are several examples on S.O. implementing countdowns identical to yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval):

```js
var timerId;

function countDown(a) {
  var timeleft = 60 * a;
  document.getElementById('btn0000').disabled = true;
  document.getElementById('btn1000').disabled = true;

  timerId = setInterval(function() {

    var seconds = Math.floor((timeleft) % 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor((timeleft / 60) % 60);
    document.getElementById("countdown1").innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    timeleft -= 1;

    if (timeleft <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timerId);
      document.getElementById("countdown1").innerHTML = "Finished"
      document.getElementById('btn0000').disabled = false;
      document.getElementById('btn1000').disabled = false;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function stopTimer() {
  if (timerId) {
    clearInterval(timerId);
    document.getElementById('btn0000').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('btn1000').disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="countdown1">Timer</div>
<button id="btn0000" onclick="countDown(10)">10 min</button>
<button id="btn1000" onclick="countDown(5)">5 min</button>
<button id="btnStop" onclick="stopTimer()">Stop</button>
```

EDIT: If you would like to start counter immeadiately, you could put setInterval callback function outside and call it like:

```js
var timerId;

function countDown(a) {

  function subtractSec() {
    var seconds = Math.floor((timeleft) % 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor((timeleft / 60) % 60);
    document.getElementById("countdown1").innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    timeleft -= 1;

    if (timeleft <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timerId);
      document.getElementById("countdown1").innerHTML = "Finished"
      document.getElementById('btn0000').disabled = false;
      document.getElementById('btn1000').disabled = false;
    }
  }

  var timeleft = 60 * a;
  document.getElementById('btn0000').disabled = true;
  document.getElementById('btn1000').disabled = true;

  timerId = setInterval((() => {
    subtractSec();
    return subtractSec;
  })(), 1000);
}

function stopTimer() {
  if (timerId) {
    clearInterval(timerId);
    document.getElementById('btn0000').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('btn1000').disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="countdown1">Timer</div>
<button id="btn0000" onclick="countDown(10)">10 min</button>
<button id="btn1000" onclick="countDown(5)">5 min</button>
<button id="btnStop" onclick="stopTimer()">Stop</button>
```

Comment: I think it should be `timeId` instead of `idTimer` inside the `stopTimer` function.

Comment: There's one extra second in between the user click and the counter actually starting. Do you think this can be improved?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan this countdown will never be accurate, because the durations in the interval methods are just an indication for the system and it reactivates according to the other processing it supports.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'd use an IFEE, I've added an example showing this

Comment: @MisterJojo I think this kind of feature isn't critically enough to make this inaccurate even noticed

Comment: @guijob 176/5000
I am not of this opinion, the differences easily exceed 10ths of a second. but his question is just about how to stop, the problem of precision is not concerned